# LLDB C++ class method call with a class type

Tags: c++, debugging, lldb

Sorry for the title; I'm not very familiar with terminology. I'm interested in examining IPC interface of WebKit on MacOS; so I started to read its codebase. I also wanted to dynamically analyse it and call some functions but I don't have the knowledge on how to call this specific function below:

```
image lookup -vn WebPage::screenToRootView WebKit
1 match found in /System/Library/Frameworks/WebKit.framework/Versions/A/WebKit:
    Address: WebKit[0x00000001a033b9dc] (WebKit.__TEXT.__text + 10185744)
    Summary: WebKit`WebKit::WebPage::screenToRootView(WebCore::IntPoint const&)
     Module: file = "/System/Library/Frameworks/WebKit.framework/Versions/A/WebKit", arch = "arm64e"
     Symbol: id = {0x0000b128}, range = [0x00000001bc74b9dc-0x00000001bc74ba78), name="WebKit::WebPage::screenToRootView(WebCore::IntPoint const&)", mangled="_ZN6WebKit7WebPage16screenToRootViewERKN7WebCore8IntPointE"
```

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21096045/lldb-how-to-call-a-function-from-a-specific-library-framework) answer on here but I don't know how to define `WebCore::IntPoint`. When I tried to define it like `expr IntPoint $ffunction = (IntPoint) 0x00000001bc74b9dc` I got the error `<user expression 0>:1:1: unknown type name 'IntPoint'`. Also tried to define the type just like the answer above but no luck.

How can I call this function - or any function formatted like this - in LLDB?

Thanks